# Mongoose - filter and sort results on user input

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, search, mongoose

I want to implement a search feature in my website, which allows the user to search the database and then filter or sort the search results as needed. Something like [this](https://www.otlob.com/restaurants?user_search=&sort=&sort=rating_desc&delivery=1&is_open=1&page=1).

Is there an "efficient" way that I can search using a Schema.find() and store the result in an array of Mongoose objects, and then filter or sort this array according to user input? Or do I have to make a new query every time the user adds a new filter?

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends a lot on your architecture.  At first blush, the direct answer to your question would be to use the [query builder interface](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html). That would let you chain together where clauses and sort and limit options via chaining, eg.

```
Person.find({ occupation: /host/ }).
  where('name.last').equals('Ghost').
  where('age').gt(17).lt(66).
  where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking']).
  limit(10).
  sort('-occupation').
  select('name occupation').
  exec(callback);
```

But if you're doing a web app, one might presume that you want to respond with the first find, and then let users filter and sort from there.

In that case, you'll either need to sort and filter on the client (which isn't too hard if you're using ES6 via babel or lodash), or if your initial find returns a lot of records, you'll still need to make trips to the server and re-query the db.

Comment: Your second guess is correct. I want the user to be able to sort and filter the search result. But I am at loss about how to handle that.